# how to change AJAX call from another php file to the same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I created 2 dropdown lists where the second one is populated from database based on the option selected in the first one using Ajax.

It's working fine but I want to change the call in my ajax from  `url:"get-City.php"` to the same page instead of creating get-city.php I want to put all the code in one page.

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php'); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>demo</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<div class="">
    <label>Country :</label>
    <select name="country" id="country">
      <option value=''>------- Select --------</option>
      <?php 
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM ****'; 
foreach ($dbDB->query($query) as $row) {
echo '<option value="'.$row["Country"].'">'.$row["Country"].'</option>';
} 
      ?>
    </select>

    <label>City :</label>
    <select name="city" id="city"><option>------- Select --------</option></select>
  </div>
   </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#country").change(function() {
    var country_name = $(this).val();
    if(country_name != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url:"get-City.php",
        data:{selected_country:country_name},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response) {
          var resp = $.trim(response);
          $("#city").html(resp);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#city").html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

and City.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php'); 

        if(isset($_POST['selected_country'])) {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT City FROM **** WHERE Country = '".$_POST['selected_country']."'ORDER BY City";
        $res = $dbDB->prepare($sql);
        $res->execute();
        $count = count($res->fetchAll());

          if($count > 0) {
            echo "<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>";
        foreach ($dbDB->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["City"].'">'.$row["City"].'</option>'; } 
        }  } 
        else { header('location: ./'); }
?>
```

Now I wanted to merge both files on the same page and make the AJAX call on the same page. Here is my updated file

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['selected_country'])) {
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT City FROM **** WHERE Country = '".$_POST['selected_country']."'ORDER BY City";
$res = $dbDB->prepare($sql);
$res->execute();
$count = count($res->fetchAll());

  if($count > 0) {
    echo "<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>";
foreach ($dbDB->query($sql) as $row) {
echo '<option value="'.$row["City"].'">'.$row["City"].'</option>'; } 
}  } 
else { header('location: ./'); }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>demo</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<div class="">
    <label>Country :</label>
    <select name="country" id="country">
      <option value=''>------- Select --------</option>
      <?php 
include('connection.php');
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM **** ORDER BY Country ASC';
foreach ($dbDB->query($query) as $row) {
echo '<option value="'.$row["Country"].'">'.$row["Country"].'</option>';
} 
      ?>
    </select>

    <label>City :</label>
    <select name="city" id="city"><option>------- Select --------</option></select>
  </div>
   </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#country").change(function() {
    var country_name = $(this).val();
    if(country_name != "") {
      $.ajax({
        data:{selected_country:country_name},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response) {
          var resp = $.trim(response);
          $("#city").html(resp);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#city").html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Everytime I select a country then second dropdown list is empty. Can you please advise me what I am missing ? Thank you.

Comment: You have deleted the url from ajax request !

Comment: why not just put all php code in one funcion and then call the function.

Comment: Missing your `ajax.js` maybe?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour  it's because the ajax call is on the same page, i can remove the url

Comment: add `echo` "test" to your code and check if XHR returns "test" ?